How to grab previous word from buffer in custom company-mode backend?
I want to make my own backend for company-mode. It must be context sensitive: completion list should be build based on previous word in editor.
When I write: git res|, list should contain word "reset" but only if previous word in line is "git ".
Why this regular expression in candidates can't get previous word for me?
(require 'company)
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun get-completions (context prefix)
  ;; (message "%s -> %s" context prefix))
  (cond
    ((string= context "git")
     (cl-remove-if-not
      (lambda (item) (string-prefix-p prefix item))
      '("reset" "clone" "pull")))
    (t nil)))

(defun test-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  (interactive (list 'interactive))
  (cl-case command
    (interactive (company-begin-backend 'test-backend))
    (prefix (company-grab-word))
    (candidates (get-completions
      (when (looking-back "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\) [a-zA-Z0-9]+$") (match-string 1)) ;; context - word before prefix
      arg)))) ;; prefix

(provide 'test-backend)

